# Would questions about stargazing be on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm not an astronomer, but I do have a daughter who is fascinated with the planets and stars. I'd love to get her a telescope and start stargazing with her, but I don't know where to begin. Would absolute beginner questions be on topic here? Or is this more for professionals in the field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We will gladly accept questions at all levels. However, folks would appreciate it if they were *quality* questions.

We realize that, for beginners like yourself, the first questions that come to mind are things like "How do I get started?" and "What telescope should I buy?" Unfortunately, those kinds of questions tend to be too broad, too vague, and/or easily outdated (as new products are introduced and older ones become obsolete).

This is a question and answer site, not a discussion board. Questions should have clear, specific answers (if they are known). Asking for product recommendations fail that test. In fact, any question starting with something like "What is the best way to" is going to be mostly opinion based and is off-topic.

This isn't a good place for really basic questions that can be answered with a simple Google search or Wikipedia, such as "What is a star?"

Questions should not duplicate other questions. Check other questions on the same and similar topics to ensure that the question hasn't already been answered, even if the answer appears to be to a different question.

There are lots of great beginner questions out there just waiting to be asked.